# Is ${\bf F}_0={\bf V}_0 {\bf V}_0^H$ a locally optimal solution of $f(\bf F)$ if ${\bf V}_0$ is a locally optimal solution of $f({\bf V} {\bf V}^H)$?

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization, stationary-point

${\bf F} \in {\mathbb C}^{N \times N}$ is positive semidefinite matrix and satisfies ${\text {tr}} ({\bf F}) \leq P$. $f({\bf F}): {\mathbb C}^{N \times N} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is a real-valued and continuous differentiable function. Consider the following problem
\begin{array}\
\begin{align}
 \mathop {\min }\limits_{\bf F} \quad & f({\bf F}) \tag{1.a}\\
 \text{s.t.} \quad &  {\text {tr}}({\bf F}) \leq P, \tag{1.b}\\
 &  {\bf F} \succeq {\bf 0}. \tag{1.c}
\end{align}
\end{array}
Let $g({\bf V}) = f({\bf V} {\bf V}^H)$, where ${\bf V} \in {\mathbb C}^{N \times N}$ satisfies ${\text {tr}} ({\bf V} {\bf V}^H) \leq P$. We get problem
\begin{array}\
\begin{align}
 \mathop {\min }\limits_{\bf V} \quad & g({\bf V}) \tag{2.a}\\
 \text{s.t.} \quad &  {\text {tr}}({\bf V} {\bf V}^H) \leq P. \tag{2.b}\\
\end{align}
\end{array}
Obviously, $f({\bf F})$ and $g({\bf V})$ have the same value domain.
A solution of problem $(1)$ can thus be obtained from $\bf V$ by setting ${\bf F} = {\bf V} {\bf V}^H$, and a solution of problem $(2)$ can also be obtained from solving $(1)$ and decomposing $\bf F$.

Assume that ${\bf V}_0$ is a locally optimal solution of problem $(2)$.
Hence, for any ${\bf V} \in {\mathbb C}^{N \times N}$ satisfying $(2.b)$,
\begin{equation}
{\text{tr}} \left[ \nabla_{\bf V} g({\bf V}_0)^H \left( {\bf V} - {\bf V}_0 \right)  \right] \geq 0, 
\end{equation}
which can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
2 ~{\text{tr}} \left[ \nabla_{\bf F} f({\bf V}_0 {\bf V}_0^H)^H \left( {\bf V} - {\bf V}_0 \right) {\bf V}_0^H  \right] \geq 0.
\end{equation}
Let ${\bf F}_0 = {\bf V}_0 {\bf V}_0^H$.
Then, is ${\bf F}_0$ a locally optimal solution of problem $(1)$, i.e., for any ${\bf F} \in {\mathbb C}^{N \times N}$ satisfying $(1.b)$ and $(1.c)$, does the following inequation hold?
\begin{equation}
{\text{tr}} \left[ \nabla_{\bf F} f({\bf F}_0)^H \left( {\bf F} - {\bf F}_0 \right) \right] = {\text{tr}} \left[ \nabla_{\bf F} f({\bf V}_0 {\bf V}_0^H)^H \left( {\bf F} - {\bf V}_0 {\bf V}_0^H \right) \right] \geq 0.
\end{equation}

I have checked some simple scalar cases and found it is true.
But I don't know if it is correct for the genereal matrix case.
Could anyone provide some hints or references? I would be very appreciated.